# Loop through 3 json file data and their comparison

Tags: python, json, pandas

[image]

Would like to compare 3 data in 3 different Json files.

Design checklist data

[image]

Assigned data

[image]

Std parameters

[image]

Conditions to be fulfilled Assigned = _Des_Checklist data --> Matched Assigned = '_Std_IBH_OL_parameters data --> Matched with Std.
(Assigned != Design_Checklist data) and (Assigned !=
_Std_IBH_OL_parameters data) --> Not Matched

```
 with open('_Std_IBH_OL_parameters.json', 'r') as json_std_ibh_ol, \
    open('_APPgen_parameters.json', 'r') as json_all_para, \
    open('_Des_Checklist.json', 'r') as json_des_check:

    def Overload_Test():

        check_ibh_ol = ['s_ibh', 's_ibm', 'tib_s1', 'sw_ibf', 'sw_ibm']


        ibh_ol_data = json.load(json_std_ibh_ol)
        data_all_para = json.load(json_all_para)
        des_check_data = json.load(json_des_check)

        results = []
        results.append(['', 'Control_parameters', '', '', '', ''])

        for i, j, k in zip(check_ibh_ol, check_ibh_ol, check_ibh_ol):
            value_all_para_assigned = float(data_all_para.get(i))
            value_ibh_ol_std = float(ibh_ol_data.get(j))  
            des_values = float(des_check_data.get(k))

            print(f"Check Data = {des_values}")

            des_s_ibh = ""

            if j == 's_ibh':
                des_s_ibh = "This is a travel"
            elif j == 's_ibm':
                des_s_ibh = "This is a switch"
            elif j == 'tib_s1':
                des_s_ibh = "Initial_time"

            if (value_all_para_assigned == des_values) and (value_all_para_assigned != 
    value_ibh_ol_std):
                results.append(["Matched", j, des_s_ibh, des_values, value_ibh_ol_std, 
    value_all_para_assigned])
                print(f"Matched, {j},{des_s_ibh}, {des_values}, {value_ibh_ol_std}, 
    {value_all_para_assigned}")

            elif (value_all_para_assigned == value_ibh_ol_std) and (value_all_para_assigned 
    != des_values):
                results.append(["Matched with std.", j, des_s_ibh, des_values, 
    value_ibh_ol_std, value_all_para_assigned])
                print(f"Matched with std., {j},{des_s_ibh}, {des_values}, 
    {value_ibh_ol_std}, {value_all_para_assigned}")

            elif (value_all_para_assigned != value_ibh_ol_std) and (value_all_para_assigned 
    != des_values):
                results.append(["Not Matched", j, des_s_ibh, des_values, value_ibh_ol_std, 
    value_all_para_assigned])
                print(f"Not Matched, {j},{des_s_ibh}, {des_values}, {value_ibh_ol_std}, 
    {value_all_para_assigned}")

        df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Remark', 'Parameter', 'Description', 
    'Design_Checklist_data', 'Standard/default', 'Assigned'])

        #df = df[df['Design_Checklist_data'] != 0]

        # Apply the background color style to the DataFrame based on the "Not Matched" 
    condition
        styled_df = df.style.map(
            lambda x:   "background-color: red" if x == 'Not Matched' else (
                        "background-color: aquamarine" if x == 'Matched with std.' else
                        "background-color: lightgreen" if x == 'Matched' else None)
        )

        # Display or print the styled DataFrame
        print(styled_df)

        styled_df.to_excel('Checklist.xlsx', sheet_name='Parameters', engine='openpyxl', 
    index=False, na_rep='NA',
                           freeze_panes=(1, 0))

        excel_file_path = 'Checklist.xlsx'
        wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
        ws = wb['Parameters']
        ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions

        for col in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']:

            max_width = 0

            for row_number in range(1, ws.max_row + 1):

                if len(str(ws[f'{col}{row_number}'].value)) > max_width:
                    max_width = len(ws[f'{col}{row_number}'].value)

            ws.column_dimensions[col].width = max_width + 1

        wb.save(excel_file_path)
        os.system("start Checklist.xlsx")

    Overload_Test()
```

It is spilling

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyLearning\Project_Start\Model\Test_02.py", line 433, in <module>
    Overload_test()
  File "D:\pyLearning\Project_Start\Model\Test_02.py", line 377, in Overload_test
    value_all_para_assigned = float(data_all_para.get(i))   # All_Parameters_assigned
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: You can't just dump code on us.  You need to **show** us the results of this code, and **explain** specifically how those results aren't what you wanted.

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Please edit the question and add the **complete** error traceback message.

Comment: The column F is the value to be checked whether it is matching with column D or column E with the help of three files. @JohnGordon

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyLearning\Project_Start\Model\Test_02.py", line 433, in <module>
    Overload_test()
  File "D:\pyLearning\Project_Start\Model\Test_02.py", line 377, in Overload_test
    value_all_para_assigned = float(data_all_para.get(i))   # All_Parameters_assigned
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType' '

Comment: Okay, so `data_all_para.get(i)` returned None, meaning there is at least one item in `data_all_para` that is missing one of the expected keys.  How do you want to handle missing keys?

Comment: It is coming from the Des_Checklist file. Missing values should be left blank in xl file. Can this be possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible, you can write the code to make it do anything you want.  So add some code that checks if the key is missing, and then handle that however you want.  Only call `float()` if the key is found.

Comment: `des_values = float(des_check_data.get(k,0))` This line actually eliminates but it inserts zeros in cells which are not intended

Comment: Okay, so ... don't do it that way?  Do it whatever way you want.

Comment: `        def remove_zeros(value):
            return '' if value == 0 else value
        df['Design_Checklist_data'] = df['Design_Checklist_data'].apply(remove_zeros)`

This is working.

Comment: Please look at how the question looks like -- and if it's mess, do not post it. Fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will ensure next time @JamesZ.